# Create a file with an input

Tags: python, file, input, with-statement, getopenfilename

I have an issue with an open file. First I need to design the name of my file, then it supposed to create a file in a block note with format .txt. Also, I have to use %less in order to print the file.

This is my code:

```
    def file():
       name=str(input("write the name of your file: ")) 
       content=str(input("write : "))

       with open(name+".txt" , "w") as newfile:
         newfile.write(content)
       %less name.txt

    file()
    leer_libro("name.txt") #it counts my letters of each line
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Your code should work if you answer `name`.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: That's not detailed enough.

Comment: You should probably end the file with a newline if you want to use normal Unix tools.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass on an absolute path to `with`.
Example:

```
with open("D:/PYTHON/03_Coding_Rule/name.txt", "a") as fi:
```

Please enter an **absolute path**

Are you having this problem?